# Django form not rendering widgets

Tags: python, html, django, forms, widget

I want to add placeholders to my fields but for some reason, this is not working. When I view page source, the placeholder attributes are not even there.

Here is my forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}),        
            'email' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'password1' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}),
        }
```

This is the template I am using for HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<section class="container">
  <div class="row centre-v">
    <div class="card login-card">
      <div class="main card-block">
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        <div class="login-or">
          <hr class="hr-or">
        </div>
        <form action="." method="post" class="register-form">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
            <p>
              {{ field }}
              {% for error in field.errors %}
              <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>{{ error }}</strong></div>
              {% endfor %}
            </p>
          {% endfor %}
          <div class="btn-login">
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Register">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields) for `ModelForm`, the `Meta` class is only used to generate fields from the underlying model. Fields which are declared explicitly in the ModelForm class are not affected by the attributes set in `Meta`. You declare `email` in your class, and `password1` and `password2` are declared in the inherited `UserCreationForm` class. (`username` is generated automatically, so the widget attribute you set in the `Meta` class may have worked for that field.) To set attributes for declared fields you can use the `self.fields` dict.

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Username'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Email'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'
```